# Powershell Combine Arrays, working code, but slow

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, office365

after researching how to combine arrays, using information I found here and in other sources I was able to create a script that takes multiple arrays and combines them on a primary key (userprincipalname). The purpose of the script is to combine licensing and usage statistics from Office 365 with information about the user account in Active Directory.

The block of code I am interested in improving is the final step where I combine the three sources of data. While my code works, it takes over 30 minutes to run. Primarily I believe this is due to how I loop through and have each record processed separately. At this point, while the code works, it's actually significantly faster to simply open the spreadsheets and perform a VLOOKUP in Excel.

Here is the code to combine the three arrays:

```
$MBInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\MBStats.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName
$LicInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\LicStats.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName
$ADInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\ADUserInfo.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName

$ADInfoCC | ForEach-Object {
$gumdrop = $_
[PSCustomObject]@{
    'Windows Username' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).WindowsUserName
    'User Principal Name' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).UserPrincipalName
    'Display Name' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).DisplayName
    'Last Name' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).LastName
    'First Name' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).FirstName
    'Email Address' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).EmailAddress
    'Employee Number' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).EmployeeNumber
    'Description' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).Description
    'Employee Type' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).EmployeeType
    'Division' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).Division
    'Department' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).Department
    'Account Enabled' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).AccountEnabled
    'Last Windows Logon' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).LastWindowsLogon
    'Last Mailbox Access' = $MBInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).LastMailboxLogon
    'Office 365 License' = $LicInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).License
    'Mailbox Size' = $MBInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).MailboxSize
    'Mailbox Type' = $MBInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).MailboxType
    'Account Expiration Date' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).AccountExpirationDate
    'Password Last Set' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).PasswordLastSet
    'Password Has Expired' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).PasswordExpired
    'Password Not Required' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).PasswordNotRequired
    'Password Never Expires' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).PasswordNeverExpires
    'User Cannot Change Password' = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName}).CannotChangePassword
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\Work\FullUserReport.xlsx -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize -BoldTopRow
```

So as you can read in the code, the way this works is that I load all three excel sheets into separate arrays, each of them has a UserPrincipalName field. The AD information has all users regardless of whether they are a mailbox user or not so I use that as the primary. I loop through that list matching the fields. I also use the import-excel module rather than import-csv so as to have the ability to apply a little formating. I added the Sort-Object to the arrays yesterday to see if ordering the list would improve performance, it did to some extent as the run time dropped from over 40 minutes to just over 30.

Thanks,
Clark

Comment: You are running a ton of where filters, and each time you are filtering through an entire spreadsheet. If you combined the objects first, then pulled the data, you would be much more efficient. Something that could make that easy is [Join-Object](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) by Warren Frame.

Comment: You can assign the filtered object and use it, rather than filtering using a where everytime. Ex: $UsrPrinInstance = $ADInfoCC.Where({$PSItem.UserPrincipalName -eq $gumdrop.UserPrincipalName})
...
'Windows Username' = $UsrPrinInstance.WindowsUserName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BenH's comment to try Join-Object from Warren Frame led me to trying Join-Object again, previously I had used a Join-Object module I downloaded from Microsoft, however it would not join the data properly (seemed like an inner join no matter what type I set). Warren's Join however does work.

Using it I now have this code that completes in a few minutes:

```
$MBInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\MBStats.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName
$LicInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\LicStats.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName
$ADInfoCC = Import-Excel C:\Work\ADUserInfo.xlsx | Sort-Object -Property UserPrincipalName

$combo1 = Join-Object -Left $ADInfoCC -LeftJoinProperty UserPrincpalName -Right $MBInfoCC -RightJoinProperty UserPrincipalName -LeftProperties 'Windows UserName',UserPrincipalName,'Display Name','Last Name','First Name','Email Address','Employee Number',Description,'Employee Type',Division,Department,'Account Enabled','Last Windows Logon','Account Expiration Date','Password Last Set','Password Has Expired','Password Not Required','Password Never Expires','User Cannot Change Password' -RightProperties 'Mailbox Size','Last Mailbox Access','Mailbox Type' -Type AllInLeft

Join-Object -Left $combo1 -LeftJoinProperty UserPrincpalName -Right $LicInfoCC -RightJoinProperty UserPrincpalName -LeftProperties 'Windows UserName',UserPrincipalName,'Display Name','Last Name','First Name','Email Address','Employee Number',Description,'Employee Type',Division,Department,'Account Enabled','Last Windows Logon','Account Expiration Date','Password Last Set','Password Has Expired','Password Not Required','Password Never Expires','User Cannot Change Password','Mailbox Size','Last Mailbox Access','Mailbox Type' -RightProperties License -Type AllInLeft | Export-Excel C:\Work\FullUserReport.xlsx -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize -BoldTopRow
```

Comment: This is the way I ended up completing this script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of arrays, I'd create hashtables, using the UserPrincipalName as the key,
eg:

```
$MBInfoCC = @{}

 Import-Excel C:\Work\MBStats.xlsx |
 ForEach-Object  {$MBInfoCC[$_.UserPrincipalName] = $_}

$LicInfoCC = @{}

Import-Excel C:\Work\LicStats.xlsx |
ForEach-Object {$LicInfoCC[$_.UserPrincipalName] = $_}

$ADUserInfo = @{}

Import-Excel C:\Work\ADUserInfo.xlsx |
ForEach-Object {$ADUserInfo[$_.UserPrincipalName] = $_}
```

Now you can reference them directly by the hashtable keys, without needing the .where() searches.

Comment: Yes, and additionally store the found item in a variable instead of re-accessing it many times: `$mb = $MBInfoCC[$_.UserPrincipalName]` then reference it in PSCustomObject hashtable `'Mailbox Size' = $mb.MailboxSize; 'Mailbox Type' = $mb.MailboxType;`